# How do I Decode OAUTH created_at response?

Tags: api, rest, oauth

I have an API where I have created a token and it has replied with.

```
expires_in=7776000
created_at=1463347242
```

`expires_in` seems to be seconds (also what the spec calls for) `7776000 / 60 / 60 / 24 = 90` days

However I have no idea how to even begin to decode the `created_at` response and the endpoint doesn't have any documentation on it.

Answer (score 1):

The `created_at` value is just the unix timestamp in seconds the token was created at. In your case it is the *RFC 2822* date `Sunday, 15-May-16 21:20:42 UTC`. For this field I couldn't find a specification, but it seems to be a common field to many implementations. With it you can calculate the absolute timestamp of expiration: `expires_at = created_at + expires_in`